# How do I use v-if statement to show static image in vuejs

Tags: image, vue.js

I want to show a static image if no image is uploaded in vuejs.

Code

```
<img :src="sub_section.imageURL ? sub_section.imageURL: '@/assets/images/upload.png'"  alt="">
```

but it is not working. how do I go about it?

Comment: what you are getting in the imageURL? check the browser inspect element and check what is print there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `v-if` specifically then you don't need to use `ternary` operator. You can try this way to show default image using `v-if` and `v-else`.

```
<img v-if="sub_section && sub_section.imageURL" :src="sub_section.imageURL" alt="uploaded-image">
<img v-else src="@/assets/images/upload.png"  alt="default-image">
```

Here, in the above code, if you get something in `sub_section` and `imageURL` both then `v-if` block will be executed, or else default image will be shown by executing `v-else` block.

You need to make sure that you apply condition for both `sub_section` and `imageURL` because there's a possibility that you might not get anything in the first variable `sub_section` itself, which might throw an error if you would be directly using `sub_section.imageURL` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img :src="sub_section.imageURL ? require(sub_section.imageURL): require('@/assets/images/upload.png')"  alt="">
```